# Gmail аккаунты и бан приложения в Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, gmail

Насколько я знаю, в случае бана приложения в Google Play Google блокирует и аккаунт разработчика, и gmail аккаунт (почтовый ящик). Можно ли, для того чтобы предотвратить потерю почтового ящика, создать второй gmail аккаунт на тот же мобильный номер (на который был создан первый gmail аккаунт)? Что произойдёт в случае бана приложения - заблокируется только один почтовый ящик, к которому привязан аккаунт разработчика, или же будут заблокированы оба ящика? Кто-либо сталкивался с такой ситуацией? Или какие есть другие способы предотвращения потери почтового ящика в случае бана приложения в Google Play?

**UPD**

Всё, что я нашла по этому поводу от Google - это статья [Protect your developer account](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2543765):

> **Use a different account for your developer account**
>
> If your developer account is linked to your personal Google Account,
> consider creating a
> new account to use for your developer account. This way, if one
> account is compromised, the other account can still be secure.
>
> If you’ve already registered, our support team can transfer your apps
> to a new account. To transfer your apps to a different account,
> register a new developer account, then prepare and request the
> transfer with our support team.
>
> Note: If you close your old account, we will refund your original $25
> registration fee.

Но всё-таки, кажется, [создание второго аккаунта мало чем может обезопасить](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-have-multiple-Google-Play-developer-accounts):

> But not to Forget if you are using same pc/laptop/device for uploading
> apps and if one developer account suspended then other accounts will
> be suspended in future.
>
> ...
>
> Unofficially you can have many, but if 1 gets suspended you all
> accounts will be in danger.

Т.е, если один аккаунт будет заблокирован, то и второй тоже с большой вероятностью может быть заблокирован... Так ли это?

И может ли помочь завести второй аккаунт на другой номер телефона, используя те же фамилию-имя?

Comment: Разве гугл требует уникальный телефон для каждого аккаунта? Если нет, то в чем проблема

Comment: @Zergatul, меня интересует, что произойдёт в случае бана приложения - заблокируется только один почтовый ящик, к которому привязан аккаунт разработчика, или же будут заблокированы оба ящика